# Why we're saying1024KB = 1MB

Tags: memory

Normally we said that 1000m= 1Km, 1000ml= 1Liter  and 1000g = 1Kg. Then why we say 1024 KB =1MB, instead of 1000 KB= 1MB. How 1024 kb is said to be as 1 mb.?

Comment: One word: binary. It's a lot easier for computers to deal with powers of 2 than with powers of 10.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: You surely could have googled that question...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1byte = 8bits which is 2 power 3 bits. If it was 1000kib =1mb it would be harder to converts into bits and vvice versa. As 1024 is the integer which is closer to 1000 and can be expressed as power of 2. It has been choosen.

Hope that helps! Sorry for my bad english and poor explanation :P

Comment: 1000 B is 1KB, 1024 is 1KiB, pay to it some attention 1KB != 1KiB

Comment: **@Mykola** Thanks! didnt know that. :)

Comment: Its general misunderstanding (very huge I think)!

Comment: Thanks for you kind explanation